# How to link with linux/gpio.h?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, makefile, linker-errors

I want to compile following c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <../deps/linux/gpio.h>

int main(void) {
    int r = gpio_is_valid(31);

    if (r == -1) {
        perror("GPIO address is invalid.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My **Makefile** looks as

```
build: gpio

LDFLAGS = -Llinux

gpio:
    $(CC) -o gpio.o src/gpio.c $(LDFLAGS)
```

Unfortunately I get "gpio.h not found" as error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gpio.h` is a Linux kernel header. It can not be used for user space programs.

Comment: does FreeBSD allow access to sys/dev/gpio.h in userspace or is a driver required too?

Comment: You have access, and you could `#include` it, but this would most propably be of no help as after compilation you need to link against what the kernel header prototyped and yo are using (here `gpio_is_valid()`, but there is nothing to link against as kernel objects are not accessable from user space.

Comment: found ioctl.h which fits my need. Thank you!